# Can the PHP $_GET be used to get a variable in the URL using Hashchange?

Tags: php, jquery, hashchange

```
<a href="#create=1">Click Me</a>
<script src="https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-hashchange/v1.3/jquery.ba-          hashchange.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).hashchange(function () {
    //
    });
</script>
```

When Click Me is clicked the URL looks like this "www.mydomain.com/#create=1".

What I am trying to do is us the $_GET in PHP to bring down the parameter.  Ex:

```
<?php echo $_GET['create'];?>
```

Using the

```
<a href="?create=1">Click Me</a>
```

works, but it reloads the page and that is what I am trying to avoid.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new future for that:

```
window.history.pushState("Remember me!", "Changing the get Parameter...", "?create=1");
```

You can apply this to all links by using this:

```
$("a").click(function() {

    if ($(this).attr("href").substr(0, 1) != "#") {
        $("body").load($(this).attr("href"));
        window.history.pushState("Remember me!", "Nothing special", $(this).attr("href"));
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: How would the html look for that.

Comment: That worked but now since the page is not reloading, how do I bring the parameter in the to display in the page.

Answer (score 2):

PHP runs on the server. A request **has** to be sent to the server for PHP to know what is in the query string. You don't need to reload the whole page but you will need to send something to the server, e.g. in an AJAX request and do something with the result.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am understanding what you are trying to say.  Is there a way you can provide me with a simple example???  If possible ofcourse.

Answer (score 2):

//java script code

```
$("#clickme").click(function(event) {
    var arr = $(this).attr('href').split('#');
    var arr=(arr[1]);
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load("data.php?"+ arr);   
});

//html code 

<a id="clickme" href="#create=1">Click Me</a>  
<div id="content"></div>

// php code

data.php
```

Comment: Let me try it out.  Thank You